# Transitive sets in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

[image: Table Definition]

The set of three pairs { (x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)} are said to be transitive if y1= x2 and x3 =x1 and y3 = y2.

Write a query to output all such transitive sets.

[image: Sample Test Case]

Comment: I'd like to see a PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: There is no PRIMARY KEY. This is my assignment. It driving me crazy. I've been at it for hours.

Answer (score 0):

I see this as a series of joins. You can use `row_number()` to generate primary keys. Your requirement translates as:

```
with data as (select t.*, row_number() over(order by null) rn from mytable t)
select
from data d1
inner join data d2 
    on  d2.x  =  d1.y 
    and d2.rn <> d1.rn
inner join data d2 
    on  d3.x  =  d1.x 
    and d3.y  =  d2.y
    and d3.rn <> d2.rn 
    and d3.rn <> d1.rn
```